# Mobile Safari scrollTo w/ textarea bug

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

Have stumbled upon what seems to be a bug with how mobile safari renders the cursor when a window.scrollTo() is executed while a user is entering text into a textarea.  Have attached source code which illustrates the issue.  I'm wondering if anyone has any advice on how I might work around this.

**The issue:**  If a user is entering text into a textarea and a window.scrollTo() is executed, the cursor remains rendered at the position the textarea **used** to be, not at it's current position.

**To recreate:**  Load the following web page using mobile safari.  Touch the textarea, which will open the keyboard.  Type a couple of characters and wait.  As text is added dynamically to the page, and the window scrolled, you'll see the cursor artifact

Have tried setting the focus() back to the textarea after the scroll, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
       textarea {
           margin-top:50px;
       }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          setTimeout(addContent,5000);
       }, false);


       function addContent() {
           var elem = document.createElement('p');
           elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some new text'))
           document.getElementById('newContentContainer').appendChild(elem);
           window.scrollTo(0,20);
           setTimeout(addContent,5000);
       }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="newContentContainer"></div>
      <div>
          <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's a photo which shows the problem: [image]

Comment: Is there a ticket open with Apple on this?

Comment: I did submit something, but haven't heard anything since...  Have moved onto other things so haven't tried with iOS 4 yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this *may* solve the problem, and most likely will also make the on-screen keyboard flash off and back on for a tiny bit too. Call this code after you use `scrollTo()`:

```
yourTextArea.blur();
yourTextArea.focus();
```

Comment: Tried this.  It does fix the issue, but I'm not happy with the abrupt opening and closing of the keyboard.  Makes it hard to continue typing if the scroll happens mid keystroke.

Comment: Well as far as I know, it's your only solution as this bug can't truly be fixed without actually fixing the software itself.